# Can't build up a connection

Tags: monero

I tried this code in my terminal:
https://xmrguide.org/tails/cli/install/terminal
*

```
*MONERO_HASH=8069012ad5e7b35f79e35e6ca71c2424efc54b61f6f93238b182981ba83f2311 \
&& MONERO_FILE=monero-linux-x64-v0.17.2.3.tar.bz2 \
&& cd ~/Persistent && wget -O $MONERO_FILE https://downloads.getmonero.org/cli/$MONERO_FILE \
&& echo "${MONERO_HASH} ${MONERO_FILE}" | sha256sum -c \
&& tar -xvf $MONERO_FILE && cd monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.17.2.3 \
&& echo "torsocks ./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address rbpgdckle3h3vi4wwwrh75usqtoc5r3alohy7yyx57isynvay63nacyd.onion:18089" > startwallet.sh \
&& printf "#\041/bin/sh\nx-terminal-emulator -e ./startwallet.sh" > startwallet.AppImage && chmod +x startwallet.AppImage \
&& chmod +x startwallet.sh && ./startwallet.sh*
```

- 

**It worked fine, I managed to unlock my wallet, but then I got this message when I tried to update the status or send money:**

*1653972008 ERROR torsocks[14514]: Host unreachable (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:539)
Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: rbpgdckle3h3vi4wwwrh75usqtoc5r3alohy7yyx57isynvay63nacyd.onion:18089. Daemon either is not started or wrong port was passed. Please make sure daemon is running or change the daemon address using the 'set_daemon' command.
1653972012 ERROR torsocks[14514]: Host unreachable (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:539)
Background refresh thread started
1653972019 ERROR torsocks[14514]: Host unreachable (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:539)
1653972025 ERROR torsocks[14514]: Host unreachable (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:539)*

**How can I resolve this?
I am using Tails 5.0 and the newest version of monero.**

**I have tried all of this:**
My monero daemon suddenly can't connect to the internet. The wallet gives me following error log:

Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: http://localhost:18081. Daemon either is not started or wrong port was passed. Please make sure daemon is running or change the daemon address using the 'set_daemon' command.

**The started daemon gives me following error log:**

2022-05-28 08:26:03.094 I Synced 2633217/2633217

2022-05-28 08:26:03.094 I SYNCHRONIZED OK

2022-05-28 08:26:03.094 I

2022-05-28 08:26:03.095 I **********************************************************************

2022-05-28 08:26:03.095 I You are now synchronized with the network. You may now start monero-wallet-cli.

2022-05-28 08:26:03.095 I

2022-05-28 08:26:03.095 I Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.

2022-05-28 08:26:03.095 I **********************************************************************

1653726482 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653726610 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653726736 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653726861 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653727108 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653727109 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653727234 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653727245 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653727471 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653727533 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653727556 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653727556] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653727681 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653727681] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653727688 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653727688 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653727688] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653727813 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653727944 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653727944 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653728077 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653728144 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653728452 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653728464 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653728589 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653728715 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653728842 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653728842 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653728985 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653729110 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653729235 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

2022-05-28 09:13:57.377 W No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers allow port 18080

1653729392 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653729397 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653729398 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653729593 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653729655 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653729795 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653729795 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653729841 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653729966 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653729990 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653729990] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 89.233.43.71

1653729990 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653729990] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 89.233.43.71

1653730016 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653730058 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653730058] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653730075 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653730075] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653730086 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653730086] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653730092 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653730092] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653730123 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653730123] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653730123 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653730123] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653730153 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653730217 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653730217] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653730233 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653730233] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653730302 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653730342 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653730342] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653730440 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653730442 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

2022-05-28 09:34:06.008 I [91.198.115.40:18280 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2633253 -> 2633256 [Your node is 3 blocks (6.0 minutes) behind]

2022-05-28 09:34:06.008 I SYNCHRONIZATION started

2022-05-28 09:34:07.824 I Synced 2633256/2633256

2022-05-28 09:34:07.825 I SYNCHRONIZED OK

1653730452 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653730453 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653730668 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653730668 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653730670 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653730797 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653730797 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653730798 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653730930 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653731078 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653731392 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653731525 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653731526 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653731571 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653731571 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653731720 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653731832 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653731957 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653731958 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653732052 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653732187 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653732320 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653732321 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653732383 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653732505 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653732565 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653732669 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653732748 ERROR torsocks[12091]: Connection refused to Tor SOCKS (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:543)

1653732772 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

2022-05-28 10:13:58.275 W No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers allow port 18080

1653732885 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653733010 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653733096 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653733097 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653733253 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653733332 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653733501 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653733699 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653733760 ERROR torsocks[12091]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)

1653733827 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653734024 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653734112 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653734118 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653734157 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653734165 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653734165] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653734165 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653734165] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 89.233.43.71

1653734165 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653734165] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

It reaches 100%, but can't connect afterwards, no matter how much time it runs.
Here the log 2 error from the daemon:
Log level is now 2

status

2022-05-28 10:37:13.166 D Read command: status

1653734287 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

1653734290 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653734290] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653734290 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653734290] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

1653734290 ERROR torsocks[12091]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)

[1653734290] libunbound[12091:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 109.69.8.51

2022-05-28 10:38:12.187 D Destructing connection #221 to 0.0.0.0

2022-05-28 10:38:12.187 I 0Connect failed to 104.238.221.81:18080

2022-05-28 10:38:12.187 D Connecting to 136.244.105.131:18080(peer_type=1, last_seen: never)...

2022-05-28 10:38:12.188 D Spawned connection #222 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:13

2022-05-28 10:38:12.188 D test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2

2022-05-28 10:38:12.188 D connections_ size now 1

2022-05-28 10:38:12.188 D Trying to connect to 136.244.105.131:18080, bind_ip = 0.0.0.0

2022-05-28 10:38:17.301 D Destructing connection #222 to 0.0.0.0

2022-05-28 10:38:17.301 I 0Connect failed to 136.244.105.131:18080

2022-05-28 10:38:17.301 D Connecting to 176.9.0.187:18080(peer_type=1, last_seen: never)...

2022-05-28 10:38:17.301 D Spawned connection #223 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:13

2022-05-28 10:38:17.301 D test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2

2022-05-28 10:38:17.301 D connections_ size now 1

2022-05-28 10:38:17.301 D Trying to connect to 176.9.0.187:18080, bind_ip = 0.0.0.0

2022-05-28 10:38:22.551 D Destructing connection #223 to 0.0.0.0

2022-05-28 10:38:22.551 I 0Connect failed to 176.9.0.187:18080

2022-05-28 10:38:22.551 D Connecting to 212.83.172.165:18080(peer_type=1, last_seen: never)...

2022-05-28 10:38:22.551 D Spawned connection #224 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:13

2022-05-28 10:38:22.551 D test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2

2022-05-28 10:38:22.551 D connections_ size now 1

2022-05-28 10:38:22.552 D Trying to connect to 212.83.172.165:18080, bind_ip = 0.0.0.0

2022-05-28 10:38:46.389 I Found "350000:74da79f6a136969abd6364bd3d37af273c408d6471e8ab598e80569b42415f86" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.389 I Found "500000:2428f0dbe49796be05ed81b347f53e1f7f44aed0abf641446ec2b94cae066b02" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.389 I Found "325000:4260d56368267bc2a70dd58d73c5ecf23b4e4d96e63c29a868e4a679b0741c7f" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.389 I Found "700000:12be9b3d210b93f574d2526abb9c1ab2a881b479131fd0d4f7dac93875f503cd" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.389 I Found "913193:5292d5d56f6ba4de33a58d9a34d263e2cb3c6fee0aed2286fd4ac7f36d53c85f" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.389 I Found "600000:f5828ebf7d7d1cb61762c4dfe3ccf4ecab2e1aad23e8113668d981713b7a54c5" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.389 I Found "900000:d9958d0e7dcf91a5a7b11de225927bf7efc6eb26240315ce12372be902cc1337" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.389 I Found "1288616:875ac1bc7aa6c5eedc5410abb9c694034f9e7f79dce4c60698baf37009cb6365" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.389 I Found "800000:2ced10aa85357ab6c14bb12b6b56d1dde28940820dda30911b73a5cc9a301760" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.389 I Found "650000:1d567f2b491324375a825895c5e7b52857b38e4fed0e42c40909c2d52240b4e0" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.389 I Found "450000:4d098b511ca97723e81737c448343cfd4e6dadb3d8a0e757c6e4d595e6e48357" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.390 I Found "550000:c2e80a636438bd9f7a7ab432a6ad297e35540d80ff5b868bca098124cad2ff8c" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.390 I Found "850000:00e2b557dde9fd4a9e2e3dd7ddac962f5ca475eb1095bc50aa757fd1218ab0a5" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.390 I Found "233000:4f69bec2af6c0852412bdd10c19e6af10c8d738fe2618b5511a98efd03ab477e" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.390 I Found "1680000:898c0e0b338edc5edd850d241578027f489167cf7b3edb33ed9d08274e15e20e" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.390 I Found "913269:f8302e6b8ba1c49aad9a854b8d6c79d8272c6239dcbba5a75ed0784c1d4f56a1" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.390 I Found "400000:1b2b0e7a30e59691491529a3d506d1ba3d6052d0f6b52198b7330b28a6f1b6ac" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.390 I Found "375000:c80c23e387585e12ffb6649d678e9ba328181797b9583a6d8911b77e25375737" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.390 I Found "250000:f59d31839bd909ec8830b4f7f66ff213f0bd006334c8523daee452725e5c7a79" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:46.390 I Found "300000:0c1cd46df6ccff90ec4ab493281f2583c344cd62216c427628990fe9db1bb8b6" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.co

2022-05-28 10:38:47.868 I Found "350000:74da79f6a136969abd6364bd3d37af273c408d6471e8ab598e80569b42415f86" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.868 I Found "650000:1d567f2b491324375a825895c5e7b52857b38e4fed0e42c40909c2d52240b4e0" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.868 I Found "913269:f8302e6b8ba1c49aad9a854b8d6c79d8272c6239dcbba5a75ed0784c1d4f56a1" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.868 I Found "1680000:898c0e0b338edc5edd850d241578027f489167cf7b3edb33ed9d08274e15e20e" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.868 I Found "325000:4260d56368267bc2a70dd58d73c5ecf23b4e4d96e63c29a868e4a679b0741c7f" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.868 I Found "700000:12be9b3d210b93f574d2526abb9c1ab2a881b479131fd0d4f7dac93875f503cd" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.868 I Found "550000:c2e80a636438bd9f7a7ab432a6ad297e35540d80ff5b868bca098124cad2ff8c" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.868 I Found "900000:d9958d0e7dcf91a5a7b11de225927bf7efc6eb26240315ce12372be902cc1337" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.868 I Found "500000:2428f0dbe49796be05ed81b347f53e1f7f44aed0abf641446ec2b94cae066b02" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.869 I Found "233000:4f69bec2af6c0852412bdd10c19e6af10c8d738fe2618b5511a98efd03ab477e" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.869 I Found "400000:1b2b0e7a30e59691491529a3d506d1ba3d6052d0f6b52198b7330b28a6f1b6ac" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.869 I Found "450000:4d098b511ca97723e81737c448343cfd4e6dadb3d8a0e757c6e4d595e6e48357" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.869 I Found "300000:0c1cd46df6ccff90ec4ab493281f2583c344cd62216c427628990fe9db1bb8b6" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.869 I Found "375000:c80c23e387585e12ffb6649d678e9ba328181797b9583a6d8911b77e25375737" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.869 I Found "913193:5292d5d56f6ba4de33a58d9a34d263e2cb3c6fee0aed2286fd4ac7f36d53c85f" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.869 I Found "600000:f5828ebf7d7d1cb61762c4dfe3ccf4ecab2e1aad23e8113668d981713b7a54c5" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.869 I Found "800000:2ced10aa85357ab6c14bb12b6b56d1dde28940820dda30911b73a5cc9a301760" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.869 I Found "850000:00e2b557dde9fd4a9e2e3dd7ddac962f5ca475eb1095bc50aa757fd1218ab0a5" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.869 I Found "250000:f59d31839bd909ec8830b4f7f66ff213f0bd006334c8523daee452725e5c7a79" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

2022-05-28 10:38:47.869 I Found "1288616:875ac1bc7aa6c5eedc5410abb9c694034f9e7f79dce4c60698baf37009cb6365" in TXT record for checkpoints.moneropulse.net

I tried to change (as well as add to the 18081) to firewall port to 18080, but the daemon gives me following message:

2022-05-28 11:01:21.426 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.3.2-release)

2022-05-28 11:01:21.426 I Initializing cryptonote protocol...

2022-05-28 11:01:21.426 I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK

2022-05-28 11:01:21.426 I Initializing core...

2022-05-28 11:01:21.427 I Loading blockchain from folder /media/amnesia/InSterquiliniisInvenitur/Tools/Monero/.bitmonero/lmdb ...

2022-05-28 11:01:21.484 I Loading checkpoints

2022-05-28 11:01:21.488 I Core initialized OK

2022-05-28 11:01:21.488 I Initializing p2p server...

2022-05-28 11:01:21.493 F Error starting server: Failed to bind IPv4 (set to required)

2022-05-28 11:01:21.493 I Deinitializing core...

2022-05-28 11:01:21.505 I Stopping cryptonote protocol...

2022-05-28 11:01:21.505 I Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully

2022-05-28 11:01:21.505 E Exception in main! Failed to initialize p2p server.

Press enter to close

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Well, it was just informational. The newest problem ist what you can read and I don't know the next step. So what you can see is what I tried and am capable of trying. I hope that is enough to get help though.

Comment: No, it's not, because if the linked information changes or moves, your question will help no one in the future. There is no code in your question to help you with. Your question will be closed if you don't remedy that. [ask]

Comment: Should be better now.